# Sudden change of schedule to cover an other colleague

Tags: work-experience

So today (Wed) I showed up to work and my boss told me (without any notice) I had to cover a coworker's shift on this Saturday because he's unable to show up for a family funeral. My workplace has like 10 other employees, and my boss always make me the one to cover shifts which I believe is unfair.

**Question:**

Can my boss suddenly change my schedule without any early notice?

Comment: Judging by the last sentence, this isn't the first time it happened. Have you ever tried saying no?

Comment: "Can my boss suddenly change my schedule without any early notice?" Maybe, maybe not. It depends on your location, and the nature of your contract.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here.

One is whether the boss can require someone to cover a shift at short notice. Most businesses that need shift coverage will use contracts that do permit that. Illnesses and family emergencies do not always give much notice that they are going to happen.

The other issue is that you seem to be getting more than your share of these extra shifts. For that, I suggest explaining to your boss that you would prefer to work fewer short notice shifts, and request that he distribute them more evenly.